# Delete cache files with lua from inside nginx

Tags: nginx, lua

I have nginx running and it saves cache files to the local disk. I have to clear that cache from time to time manually. I thought about adding an extra location like `/clear_cache` where I delete the local files directly with Lua, since it can be embedded in nginx.
I did some research and found things like `rewrite_by_lua` or `content_by_lua`. Is it possible to access/modifiy the underlying fs with Lua or is that restricted?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah You can remove file:

```
location /clear_cache {
    content_by_lua_block {
        //file creation
        local f = assert(io.open("/newFile.txt", 'wb')) -- open in "binary" mode
        f:write(body)
        f:close()

        //Remove file
        os.remove("/newFile.txt")
    }
}
```